# How do I get part of this JSON out?

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

I understand that questions very similar to this have been posted, but JSON files are all structured rather different, and although I am very new to using JSON with VB, I'd much rather use databases, I have done it a few times and what I usually do is not working.

I have gotten down to pulling the values out of each figures array item, but once I get into it, I get errors when trying to use image2.Value("id"). So the only way I can access the correct one is to do an If statement saying that if image2.Name = "id" Then If image2.Value() = strFigID Then do something.

Here is a portion of the JSON. It is valid, this is only a portion I pulled out, not the whole JSON file.

```
"figures":[
        {
            "id":"F001",
            "title":"Figure 1.  Some Figure",
            "sheets":[
                "1047815_01.gif",
                "1057923_02.gif"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"F002",
            "title":"Figure 2.  Another Figure",
            "sheets":[
                "f110__2184_00.gif"
            ]
        }
]
```

Here is the code

```
If image.Name = "figures" Then
    Dim testingJArray As JArray = image.Value()
    For Each ArrayImage In testingJArray
        Dim jResults2 As JObject = JObject.Parse(ArrayImage.ToString())
        Dim imageResults2 As List(Of JToken) = jResults2.Children().ToList()
        Dim imageForLog2 As String = ""
        For Each image2 As JProperty In imageResults2
            imageForLog2 = image2.ToString()
            If image2.Name = "id" Then
                If image2.Value().ToString() = strFigID Then
                    ' ---------------------------------------------------
                    ' At this point I am at the correct Array Item
                    ' But now I need to get the array item out of
                    ' the sheets value
                    ' ---------------------------------------------------
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as has been noted, that is invalid JSON.  The entire thing needs to be wrapped in "{ ... }".

One way to get at the data:

```
Dim js = JObject.Parse(jstr)

strGIF = js("figures")(0)("sheets")(0)   ' == 1047815_01.gif
```

It might be easier to define classes to use:

```
Public Class Figure
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property sheets As String()
End Class

Public Class FigsContainer
    Public Property figures As Figure()
End Class
```

To use them:

```
Dim figs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FigsContainer)(jstr)

Dim s = figs.figures(0).sheets(0)   ' 1047815_01.gif again
```

Whether the classes are worth it or not depends on whether you will be working with the data or just need one value in the json string.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, i'd try to use a type structure to parse JSON, something like this:

```
public class Figure
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<string> sheets { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Figure> figures { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can simple invoke `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Figure>` to get objects and use LINQ to find whatever you need

Also, your JSON seems to be invalid, it needs `{}` braces

Comment: There is more to it, I just pulled out the "figures" portion. Where are the missing {}?

Comment: AFAIR, JSON must look like: {"figures":[{...},{...}]}